# Split an array into bins of equal numbers

Tags: arrays, numpy, scipy, vectorization, binning

I have an array (not sorted) of N elements. I'd like to keep the original order of N, but instead of the actual elements, I'd like them to have their bin numbers, where N is split into m bins of equal (if N is divisible by m) or nearly equal (N not divisible by m) values. I need a vectorized solution (since N is fairly large, so standard python methods won't be efficient). Is there anything in scipy or numpy that can do this?

```
e.g.
N = [0.2, 1.5, 0.3, 1.7, 0.5]
m = 2
Desired output: [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

I've looked at numpy.histogram, but it doesn't give me unequally spaced bins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listed in this post is a NumPy based vectorized approach with the idea of creating equally spaced indices for the length of the input array using [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -
Here's the implementation -

```
def equal_bin(N, m):
    sep = (N.size/float(m))*np.arange(1,m+1)
    idx = sep.searchsorted(np.arange(N.size))
    return idx[N.argsort().argsort()]
```

Sample runs with bin-counting for each bin to verify results -

```
In [442]: N = np.arange(1,94)

In [443]: np.bincount(equal_bin(N, 4))
Out[443]: array([24, 23, 23, 23])

In [444]: np.bincount(equal_bin(N, 5))
Out[444]: array([19, 19, 18, 19, 18])

In [445]: np.bincount(equal_bin(N, 10))
Out[445]: array([10,  9,  9, 10,  9,  9, 10,  9,  9,  9])
```

---

Here's another approach using `linspace` to create those equally spaced numbers that could be used as indices, like so -

```
def equal_bin_v2(N, m):
    idx = np.linspace(0,m,N.size+0.5, endpoint=0).astype(int)
    return idx[N.argsort().argsort()]
```

Sample run -

```
In [689]: N
Out[689]: array([ 0.2,  1.5,  0.3,  1.7,  0.5])

In [690]: equal_bin_v2(N,2)
Out[690]: array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0])

In [691]: equal_bin_v2(N,3)
Out[691]: array([0, 1, 0, 2, 1])

In [692]: equal_bin_v2(N,4)
Out[692]: array([0, 2, 0, 3, 1])

In [693]: equal_bin_v2(N,5)
Out[693]: array([0, 3, 1, 4, 2])
```

Comment: I ran this for N = np.arange(1,94) and m = 10, but the binning wasn't of nearly equal sizes. I'd expect it to be mostly 9 or 10, but had bins with 6 elements and some with 11 and so on.

Comment: @max_max_mir Check out the updated version, which should be much faster too!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Divakar. The first one is still quite not there yet (it's close). If you try equal_bin(np.arange(1,91), 10), you get 9 elements in 8 bins, but you have 10 in 1 bin and 8 in the other. In this case, it should be 9 elements for each.

Answer (score 3):

#### pandas.qcut

Another good alternative is the [`pd.qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.qcut.html#pandas.qcut) from pandas. For example:

```py
In [6]: import pandas as pd
In [7]: N = [0.2, 1.5, 0.3, 1.7, 0.5]
   ...: m = 2

In [8]: pd.qcut(N, m, labels=False)
Out[8]: array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0], dtype=int64)
```

#### Tip for getting the bin middle points

If you want to return the bin edges, use `labels=True` (default). This will allow you to get the bin middle points with:

```py
In [26]: intervals = pd.qcut(N, 2)

In [27]: [i.mid for i in intervals]
Out[27]: [0.34950000000000003, 1.1, 0.34950000000000003, 1.1, 0.34950000000000003]
```

The intervals is an array of [`pandas.Interval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html) objects (when `labels=True`).

---

See also: [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.cut.html), if you would like to make the bin *width* (not bin count) equal